# Why is it called the cross-entropy of q relative to p, not p relative to q?

Tags: entropy, kullback-leibler, cross-entropy, divergence

I'm looking into the definition of cross entropy from wikipedia. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_entropy

[image]

Cross entropy is not symmetric, so I think for sure it shouldn't be called cross entropy between $p$ and $q$.
But why is it called the cross-entropy of the distribution $q$ relative to a distribution $p$, not $p$ relative to $q$?

Also from this wikipedia page, cross entropy $H(p,q)$ can be written as

$$H(p,q)=H(p)+D_{KL}(p||q)$$

where $D_{KL}(p||q)$ is the KL divergence of $p$ from $q$, or the relative entropy of $p$ with respect to $q$. Now it is $p$ with respect to $q$？

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence#Definition) calls it $KL(P||Q)$ "the relative entropy from $Q$ to $P$", so this also could be interpreted as $P$ being the "reference distribution".

The cross-entropy can be understood as the average [Huffman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding) encoding length when the distribution is *thought* to be $q$ but is actually $p$, i.e. the "real thing" is $p$. So, it makes kind of sense to consider $p$ as the distribution that is the "baseline".

Comment: Thank you. But why is $D_{KL}(p||q)$ called the relative entropy of $p$ with respect to $q$ in both the cross entropy and KL divergence wiki page?

Comment: On [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence#Definition) I could only find the expression "the relative entropy from $Q$ to $P$". But maybe sometimes someone switches it, maybe unintentionally, maybe intentionally. Anyway, what really matters is that you know what the actual meaning is.

Comment: OK, thank you. If you search "with respect to" in that page you will see it at the end of the Definition section, which is written as "Another common way to refer to $D_{KL}(P||Q)$ is as the relative entropy of $P$ with respect to $Q$".

Comment: OK, I see. But this very paragraph seems to answer your question quite comprehensively, right?

Comment: Yes, thanks. I was just wondering how to correctly write it in my thesis.

Comment: I'm not an English native speaker, but I think OP's question is appropriate and the expressions are quite "reversed". When we say "from $Q$ to $P$", typically this means $Q$ is kind of a baseline(reference) and $P$ is something that is away from the baseline. Also, "$p$ with respect to $q$" implies that $p$ is something we want to represent with $q$ as a building block(or baseline). So the expressions should be reversed, aren't they? Because $p$ is a baseline in $D_{KL}(p||q)$.